# How to Destroy Ui android Studio

Tags: android

hello im making  a Android app and having some trouble is there any way to delete ui that a script created in the script

Something like this?

Destroy(Button)
Destroy(textBox)

Comment: Don't know about destroying, but you can make them disappear: `myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: oh ok its just that it needs to be Destroyed cus its on a grid and and something can not take its playse right?

Comment: How did you create your Grid? Did you use an adapter? Can you give us more code or pictures of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting the visibility on elements you want to hide.

If you don't want it to take up the space anymore then use `GONE`:

```java
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

However, if you want it to be invisible but still take up space in the layout then use `INVISIBLE` instead:

```java
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: oh ok i was wandering what the was diff but thank you